# How to override the video tag if the video is not enabled?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="video__element">
    <video></video>
    <div id="avtar">
        <i class="fas fa-user-circle"> User Online </i>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to insert the avtar to occupy the whole **div .video__element** and disable the video tag when the content of the video is not enabled.

Comment: `video { display: none; }` ?

Comment: what do you mean by enabled ? Paused ? Without source ?

Comment: I think there is no default CSS/HTML solution for it, you need to hide and show the #avatar div depending on the src video attribute via javascript and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The content inside the opening and closing  tags is shown as a fallback in browsers that don't support the element.

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

```
<video controls>
  <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <!--Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video. Here is
     content instead. -->
  <div id="avtar">
     <i class="fas fa-user-circle"> User Online </i>
  </div>
</video>
```